# In what context would one use "verpeilt"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does "verpeilt" have negative connotations?
Is it something one does intentionally?

EDIT:
Example for my case:
"Ich hab mich irgendwie echt mega verpeilt."

EDIT 2:
The context being that the speaker had not contacted for a long while and were excusing themselves for it.

I searched online but could not get a satisfactory contextual meaning and usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One dictionary says:

> [VERB     verpeilen](https://www.dict.cc/german-english/verpeilt.html) | verpeilte | verpeilt
>   SYNO    säumig | unpünktlich | verspätet | zu spät | überfällig
>   verpeilt [ugs.]
>   dopey {adj} [coll.]
>   drugged {adj}
>   confused {adj}
>   ___jd. verpeilt etw. [ugs.] [vergisst etw.]
>   _____sth. slips sb.'s mind [coll.]
>   ___jd. hat etw. verpeilt [ugs.] [… vergessen]
>   _____sth. slipped sb.'s mind [coll.]
>   ___verpeilt sein [ugs.] [fig.] [das rechte Winkelmaß verloren haben]
>   _____to not be with it
>   ___verpeilt sein [ugs.] [Jugendsprache]
>   _____to be out of it [coll.]

That would answer your initial question with: Yes, usually *verpeilt* has negative connotations, but also: yes, sometimes this is "done" intentionally.

As this was overlooked or flat out denied as even existing in the other answers: The sub case of *verpeilt* as a negative thing that is at the same time turned into a positive thing:

As a slang expression among recreational drug users:

> Boah, ey, war ich gestern verpeilt!

This indicates that the drug – usually alcohol or marihuana – had quite an effect on cognitive (or even more basic) processes.
If taken 'medicinally' this is usually listed as (unwanted) "side-effect".

In this case *verpeilt* as in "out of one's mind" or "drugged" is an indication of strong stuff consumed in 'sufficient quantities'. And the associated state or condition is regarded as desirable among aficionados.

This is examplified in numerous song lyrics, like this one:

> Stumpf und verpeilt,
>   doch eher wie geil, so.
>   Leichtsinn befreit, wir fliegen high, so high.
>   <sub>[Rakede: Stumpf und verpeilt](https://genius.com/Rakede-stumpf-und-verpeilt-lyrics)</sub>

One of the more typical trip reports sounds like this:

> Das zweite mal habe ich auf einem Festival konsumiert, da waren es dann etwa 250mg über den Abend verteilt, ich hab am Schluss raus um 4 oder 5 morgens auch noch paar Tüten geraucht, dass ich teilweise auf der Tanzfläche zu mir gekommen bin und erstmal paar Sekunden gebraucht habe, um zu merken wo ich überhaupt bin und was ich mache. Hab dann auch überall Leute gesehen und Sachen gehört, aus den Zelten der Leute kam Musik, beim Schlafen hatte ich das Gefühl, dass ständig irgendwer im Zelt flüstert usw., **total verpeilt halt**.  Der nächste Tag war eigentlich auch garnicht so krass, wie ich es mir vorgestellt hatte, klar ich war am Arsch und wirklich gut drauf war ich auch nicht. Da aber da erst Samstag war hab ich abends mit Alkohol und Gras weitergefeiert, und es hat mir auch **Spaß gemacht.**
>   <sub>Source:[Land der Träume: Scheine auf mdma nicht klar zu kommen - LSD?](https://www.land-der-traeume.de/forum.php?t=28415)</sub>

And this confession is apparently even worn with pride by 16-year-olds on shirts printed upon school graduation:

> [image]
>   <sub>Source: [Abschlussmotive passend zum Abschlussspruch "Alle Verballert, Verpeilt, Verschallert, Druff"](https://www.schuldruckerei.com/abschluss/shirts/mottos/sonstiges_112/alle-verballert-verpeilt-verschallert-druff_1948/)</sub>

---

The updated sub question now reads

> EDIT: Example for my case: "Ich hab mich irgendwie echt mega verpeilt."

but the possible contexts around this make this very hard to pinpoint to just one translation.

One suggestion that retains most connotations might be: "I got really/somehow fucked up." In a milder way: "I (got) really screwed up."

Context dependent liberal translations:

I  was supposed to file my taxes yesterday, but I totally missed to do that on time. (Bummer!)
*Ich sollte bis gestern meine Steuern eingereicht haben, aber ich hab es total verpeilt(, das rechtzeitig zu tun).*

I took three butterfly pills at once yesterday and that somehow really fucked me up. (Look what a hero I am having fun: that was great/intense)
I habe gestern drei Schmetterlingspillen auf einmal eingenommen. Dabei hab mich irgendwie echt mega verpeilt.

---

Update2:
Given the context "that the speaker had not contacted for a long while and were excusing themselves for it."

> Ich hab mich irgendwie echt mega verpeilt.

Would become:
I had quite some other things on my mind (-> unconcentrated & disorganised) and somehow I therefore missed out big to contact you earlier.
(Meant as an excuse: it says someone was almost forced to forget by being busy.)

Comment: Etwas verpeilen wird oft metaphorisch benutzt. Das ist m.E. aber keine Nebenbedeutung, geschweige denn mehrere, sondern die einzige Bedeutung des Wortes. Entweder es ist wörtlich oder metaphorisch gemeint. Und "regarded as desirable" bedeutet ja wohl, dass der Zustand positiv bewertet wird, nicht negativ.

Comment: @LangLangC Added EDIT 2:
The context being that the speaker had not contacted for a long while and were excusing themselves for it.

Comment: @userunknown Danke für den Hinweis "positiv", war wohl zu implizit hier? – Angenommen, dass das Teil des ConnotationCrusaderCase ist: Wenn verpeilt im Drogenjargon benutzt wird, ist dann nicht "bleede" die Grundbedeutung, und "war geil" die Konnotation, Neben- oder Zusatzbedeutung?` ("An additional, not immediately obvious meaning or association attached to the main meaning of a word or phrase.")

Comment: @LangLangC: Sorry, ich verstehe nicht, was Du mit "positiv war wohl zu implizit" meinst. "ConnotationCrusaderCase" finde ich auch nicht, auch nicht wenn ich die ProgrammierSprachenSchreibWeise aufbreche. "Bleede" finde ich nicht bei dict.leo - soll es "blöde" in irgendeiner Mundart sein? Ich fürchte Du vermischst hier die Bedeutung einer Sache und die Bewertung. 2 Personen können sich über die Bedeutung sehr einig sein aber diametral entgegengesetze Bewertungen abgeben und dennoch das gleiche Wort benutzen. "Verpeilt sein" ist solch ein Ausdruck. Die Phrase allein verrät noch nicht d Haltung…

Comment: Abgesehen von "schlecht", "böse" usw. implizieren die meisten Wörter auch keine Wertung. Ist "Käse" etwas positives? Für einen Veganer ist Käse eher negativ. Soll man jetzt Mehrheitsabstimmungen veranstalten? Wenn fast jedes Wort, je nach Kontext, für etwas Positives oder Negatives genutzt werden kann, welchen Sinn hat es dann, ein Wort einer der Gruppen zuzuordnen? Dass bspw. Hunger meist negativ und Käse positiv bewertet wird ist kein Thema für sprachliche Analysen, weil man fast immer unabhängig vom Wort zum gleichen Ergebnis kommt. Bei Abwesenheit einer substantiellen Information lädt …

Comment: … es nur zu ausschweifenden Betrachtungen ein, wann etwas, das meist so ist in Ausnahmen dann doch wieder anders ist. Hier, zur kuriosen Argumentation, dass die Wirkung mit einer Nebenwirkung verbunden ist, und so von der Bedeutung auf eine Nebenbedeutung geschlossen werden kann. Ein kreativer Schachzug, aber m.E. nicht wirklich zulässig. Es geht ja beim Verpeiltsein schon spezifisch um die Nebenwirkung eines Rausches, nicht um den Rausch allgemein. "Blöde" und "war geil" sind Bewertungen, die auch ambivalent in einer Person vorkommen können aber es sind nicht die Bedeutungen von verpeilt. …

Comment: … "Oh, war das ein Käsecroissant?" "Wieso?" "Blöde - ich bin Veganer, aber schmeckt geil!". Die Bedeutung von "Käse" muss ich einem Muttersprachler nicht beibringen, ansonsten würde ich es mit "Nahrungsmittel, Milchprodukt, durch Schimmelkulturen fermentiert/gereift, ..." versuchen. Das ist die Bedeutung von "Käse" - ob ich oder der Adressat es nun blöde findet oder geil oder beides ist ohne Rückwirkung auf die allgemeine Bedeutung, auch wenn es für den Veganer persönlich bedeutet, dass er davon Abstand nimmt.

Comment: @userunknown Ich vermute da eine zu enge oder gar abweichende Definition von Wortbedeutung und/oder Konnotation als Grundlage der Kritik (wie auch im Meta-post zum Thema). Wie wäre es also mit einer Main-Frage zur genauen Erklärung dieses Wortes und seiner Verwendung? Kurze Suche beeindruckt mich jedenfalls mit Abwesenheit einer solchen Frage hier.

Comment: @LangLangC: Du kannst eine solche Frage gern stellen ohne das mit mir abzustimmen. :) In der Bewertungsfrage, da Du das nicht thematisierst, gibst Du mir also recht?

Answer (score 15):

I know two kinds of usage for "verpeilt":

- verpeilt sein
  (e.g. "Ich bin heute wieder total verpeilt") meaning to be unconcentrated
- etwas verpeilt haben
  (e.g. "wolltest du nicht dein Zimmer aufräumen?" "Ohje, das hab ich völlig verpeilt") 
  which means to have forgotten something.

Both have a slight negative, not rude, colloquial meaning

The meaning could stem from "Peilung" (seeking direction)

Comment: _The meaning __could__ stem from "Peilung"_ It does. - The original meaning is to have made a mistake when getting/measuring the bearings (peilen) so the resulting direction is off. Other uses are measuring water depth or a radio frequency. - It is colloquially used as a mildly negative but still friendly expression.

Comment: Peilen isn't only seeking direction. In nautical context it's also measuring a level. https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/peilen When you get the wrong level you get problems with your environment. I think this fits best.

Answer (score 8):

- It's usually not a positive thing to be 'verpeilt', but I'm not aware of any additional negative connotation
- It's certainly not something one does intentionally. You could be blamed for not exercising due care, though.
- You can use 'verpeilt' if someone makes an honest mistake because his train of thoughts is on the wrong track. There's an implicit error of reasoning or you're simply lacking in concentration. It's usually not a grave error. You can be called 'verpeilt' if you mess up simple calculations in your math homework, or if you try to put on your shoes the wrong way. The word is used in colloquial speech only, as far as I'm aware of.

Answer (score 4):

Since both existing answers focus on a temporary property of being unconcentrated, it's worthwhile pointing out that “verpeilt” also has a more permanent meaning which suggests a chaotic mind, a person incapable of e.g. organizing their life/work, keeping appointments, arguing coherently, etc.

For instance, a typical usage might be: “Gut, dass Barbara nicht mehr in unserem Team ist – sie ist ganz schön verpeilt; ich finde es anstrengend, mit ihr zu arbeiten.”